# Limit to Infinity of Ratio of Polynomials

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, limits-without-lhopital

Let $\lbrace a_n \rbrace$ be a sequence; then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\infty$ provided that:

$$\forall K>0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \forall n \ge N:a_n>K$$

Use this definition to prove that:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3-6n^2+1}{n^2+5}=\infty$

I've tried about as many ways to get this to work as I can think of, but nothing ever ends up working out.  I can't decide the lower bound for $N$ to choose so that I end up with the sequence always being greater than $K$.  It's just a really annoying fraction to work with.  Unfortunately I'm stuck and can't figure out the algebraic manipulation.

Comment: Can't you use the idea that $$\frac{n^3-6n^2+1}{n^2+5}=\frac{n-6+\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{5}{n}}?$$

Comment: We've only defined the limit of a ratio in the case that both the numerator and the denominator converge.  That's why I wasn't sure how to continue with an approach like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3-6n^2+1}{n^2+5}=\infty
$.

If
$f(n)
=\frac{n^3-6n^2+1}{n^2+5}
$,
then
$n^3-6n^2+1
=n^3(1-6/n)+1
\gt n^3/2
$
for $n \gt 12$
and
$n^2+5
=n^2(1+5/n^2)
\lt 2n^2$
for $n \ge 3$.

Therefore,
for $n \gt 12$,
$f(n)
=\frac{n^3-6n^2+1}{n^2+5}
\gt \frac{n^3/2}{2n^2}
=\frac{n}{4}
$.

Therefore,
to get $f(n) > K$
it is enough to choose
$n > \max(12, 4K)$.

Note that the
inequalities can be
very crude;
to prove divergence
(or convergence 
if that is what holds)
you do not need
to get anywhere near
the best possible bounds.